Firebase Custom Logs Only Showing the Latest Entry
I use the following methods to report custom logs,
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log(msg);
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new Throwable("Custom log end"));

However, when viewing "Logs and Breadcrumbs Navigation" on the Crashlytics page in the Firebase console, only the latest custom log can be viewed. In fact, the actually recorded content has a timestamp added, and it's different each time.
I report logs using the following methods. I don't know how to configure and view them in the Firebase console.
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("test", msg);
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("CustomLog", bundle);

I hope there are ways to view every custom log reported in the console. Please provide specific code and console configurations.

You need to check Firebase Analytics Console, not Crashlytics. Custom events reported using logEvent will appear there

How to configure the key event in the console? How should it be configured in the code? If it is reported, how can I view it? I've tried but didn't succeed. Please provide more detailed operations. Thank you very much.

Go to analytics dashboard and check whether it's reported under events or not

I have already added a key event named "CustomLog" to "key event". The following is my code: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("test", msg);
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent("CustomLog", bundle);

Once you click Analytics dashboard in console, scroll down until you see "Event count
by Event name" . Click "View Events" and check whether it's reported there or not

I've found the corresponding location, but it prompts "No data available". What configuration do I need to make? For example, make configurations in the Firebase console, or initialize Firebase in the code, or make configurations in gradle file?

I've seen the event, but it was postponed by one day, and I didn't see the data in the bundle that I reported.
